# Spring boot 1.3.8 + hibernate. Double initialization of ConstraintValidator on JPA side

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

This question is an often one, but I came up to new levels of it(as it seems).
Have been digging on this for a few hours.

Have a spring boot (1.3.8 release) with hibernate.

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>9</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Formed a ConstraintValidator with bean injections, which I've binded to an entity by type:
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)

On the controller side I've used @Valid annotation.

And this is what I get(specially marked the 'isValid' to logs):
Controller -> @Valid -> Logger tells the isValid is called (Validator's 'this' gives one object address)

After this there is a call to save the entity:
Controller -> Service -> JPA
And from this point I see that the isValid is called again, bumping into the null reference of the autowired bean. The logger showed that the Validator object is different and shows a different memory block for the "this" output.

When I removed the default constructor with a Constructor Injection one, I saw a more clearer picture:
hibernate.newInstance failed to locate the default constructor.

So the culprit seems to be the JPA, which is trying to create and validate the entity on save state, creating a separate instance of the validator.

And this thing is related only when I'm doing custom validations on entities. Divided this into entity-dto, having the verifications on the DTO, and everything is working like a charm.

Tried the suggestions from the net to define validators and other stuff, and nothing worked.

Can someone suggest how to do this without DTO(hate doing duplications of entity-dto)?

---

Here's an interesting thing to add.
After a few tries managed to save the bean injections using static and constructor autowire(can't tell what was I doing wrong yesterday) and the isValid started to pass. But now I get a "null id" exception on the saveAndFlush, caused by the call to JPA's generic findByIpAndIdNot.

I clearly getting more and more confused on this, because this is starting to loose sense. Before the call I get a verification that the DAO object is the same, Entity - same and etc, but at that point I catch a null pointer out of nowhere.

Tried switching from JDK 9 to 8. Nothing.